# Exception message is On data context type there is a top IQueryable property whose element type is not an entity type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm bulding a WCFDataService hosted in IIS 7, I'm  going to use Reflection Provider as data source provider.
My project works if I keep the entity type definition in the same assembly where I defined the service, but dosen't work if I move the entity type to another referenced assembly;

I get the following error:

> "server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'On data context type 'EntityContainer', there is a top IQueryable property 'Cats' whose element type is not an entity type"

Service

```
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<EntityContainer>
    {
        
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Cats", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
          
        }
    }
```

Entity Container

```
public class EntityContainer
    {
        public IQueryable<Cat> Cats
        {
            get
            {
                var s = new List<Cat>();
                var c1 = new Cat {Id = 1, Name = "Fufi"};
                var c2 = new Cat {Id = 1, Name = "Felix"};
                s.Add(c1);
                s.Add(c2);
                return s.AsQueryable();
            }
        }

    }
```

Entity type

```
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public  class Cat 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As I said above everithing work keeping the class Cat together with the other code, but I got the error moving the Cat class to a referenced assembly

What im missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 2 hours and strong head ache i found the problem by myself, I was referencing **Microsoft**.Data.Services.Client in my service and **System**.Data.Services.Client in the referenced project library  where I was going to move  the entity type. Hope my post can help someone else.

Comment: Plus one for sharing the solution although the strong headache :)

Comment: +100 already had a headache and no solution - this one saved me!

Answer (score 0):

in addition the own author answer after one day hard strong headache I found solution for EntityFramework model 6.0.4. It is need Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider assembly and WcfDataService class derive from EntityFrameworkDataService as follow:

```
    public class WcfDataService1 : EntityFrameworkDataService<EntityContainer>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
}
```