# there is a top IQueryable property 'XXX' whose element type is not an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-6, code-first

I want to create a WCF service using code first context .
So I install the follwoing packages :

```
WCF Data Services Server for OData V1-3 5.7.0 

WCF Data Services Client for OData V1-3 5.7.0
```

---

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class TweetService : DataService< Context >
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        // config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntityset", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        // config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

and remove any references to `System.Data.Services` to resolve any expected .

---

But i face the following exception :

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'On data context type 'Context', there is a top IQueryable property 'Aliases' whose element type is not an entity type. Make sure that the IQueryable property is of entity type or specify the IgnoreProperties attribute on the data context type to ignore this property.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>       at System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(ProviderMetadataCacheItem metadataCacheItem) at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata(Boolean skipServiceOperations) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateInternalProvider(Object dataSourceInstance) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider& metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider& queryProviderInstance, Object& dataSourceInstance, Boolean& isInternallyCreatedProvider) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864806/exception-message-is-on-data-context-type-there-is-a-top-iqueryable-property-who